# Exists any alternative more beautiful at this loop?

Tags: php, pointers, loops

```
$i=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
if ($i==0) echo "First"
$i++;
}
```

Access directly to mysqli pointer? a php class like's Iterator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’d use this:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    // process first item
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
        // process following items
    }
}
```

Comment: -1!  I wouldn't use this.  A while loop only executes while TRUE, which is checked first.  Therefore the IF is duplicitous as the loop wouldn't execute anyway if left alone.

Comment: @The Wicked Flea: That's wrong. The first $row = mysql_fetch_assoc() will check if there is any data (false if none), the second one will check if there is more than one row in the result set (mysql_fetch_assoc() moves the internal result pointer). So Gumbo is absolutely right.

Comment: @The Wicked Flea: That’s wrong. If the `if` contition is true, `$row` would hold the first record and can be prcessed in “process first item”. And only if there are more than one record, the `while` condition will be true and iterate the rest.

Comment: Yet you duplicate what should happen.  The boolean flag is a better method, because while always does an IF-check before executing its contents.  If there are no rows, the interior is never executed.  When a boolean/integer is initialized first and then maintained you can have your exception ... rather than a whole block of code for the first item, and a whole block for the rest.

Comment: It depends on how the first record will be processed differently from the rest. He can always adjust it to his needs. He could also use a `do-while` loop instead. It’s just the separation of first and rest that he was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = true;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($first) echo "First"
   $first = false;
}
```

Comment: To alternate rows with this method, just do $first = !$first.

Comment: True David, true.  But it's the only DRY way to do it, there's no other way.  DB objects with iterators are either rare or part of a framework.

Comment: @The Wicked Flea: Again, you’re wrong. `$first` will just be true for the first iteration. After that, `$first` is always false.

Comment: So replace it with the integer.  There's no "better" method of tracking the first row that doesn't duplicate a whole block of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the first element for something special, then maybe something like:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc();
//do stuff to first row
do {
    //do stuff to all rows (including the first)
} while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc());
```

Otherwise I have no idea what the question is and I'm not a PHP guy...

Answer (score 0):

Do not have any method for know exactly position in all moment?

for example java iterator implements next or hasNext(), if !hasNext() the item is the last.

Comment: Please edit your question and don’t use the answer function. You can implement that in object oriented way with an iterator if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

well, if i understand your question correctly, you want the first row and then iterate through the others:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(); // $row contains first row

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) { // loop through the rest of the rows

}
```